# R: Two axis chart adjustments

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, multiple-axes

I am trying to plot a chat with two axis, here is the code and attached is the plot,

I have to do two adjustments to it.

- I want to plot a line with dots and dots should be middle of the bars
- Adjusting right side axis(i.e axis(4)) tick marks should align with left side axix(i.e axis(2))

Code:

```
Region=c("North","South","East","West")
Sales=sample(500:1000,4)
Change=sample(1:10,4)/10
names(Sales)=Region
names(Change)=Region
barplot(Sales,ylim=c(0,1000))
par(new=T)
plot(Change,type="b",axes=F,ylim=c(0,1))
axis(4)
box()
```

Regards,

Sivaji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, save your barplot as some object. So you will get coordinates of the middle points. Then to add line you can use also function `lines()` and just multiply `Change` values with 1000.
Then for `axis()` function supply `at=` values and `labels=` the same as `at=`, just divided by 1000.

```
x<-barplot(Sales,ylim=c(0,1000))
lines(x,Change*1000,type="b")
axis(4,at=seq(0,800,200),labels=seq(0,800,200)/1000)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to play to set the same x-axis in the second plot, you get this info from `par("usr")`.
The `xaxs="i"` is to set the `xlim` exactly, by default R increase the xlim a bit to make it better looking.

```
par(mar=c(5,5,2,5)) # change margins
x = barplot(Sales, ylim=c(0,1000)) # barplot, keep middle points of bars
mtext("Sales", 2, line=3) # first y-axis label
xlim = par("usr")[1:2] # get xlim from plot
par(new=TRUE) 
plot.new() # new plot
plot.window(xlim=xlim, ylim=c(0,1), xaxs="i", yaxs="i") # new plot area, same xlim
lines(x,Change,type="b") # the lines in the middle points
axis(4) # secondary y-axis
mtext("Change", 4, line=3) # secondary y-axis label
box()
```

[image: the plot]